# Convert sed replace rule to batch/windows

Tags: batch-file, sed

I am trying to replace a version number in my bower file with one supplied to the batch file. In *nix with "sed" available to me this would be easy and done as follows:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(\"version\":\).*/\1\"$RELEASE_NUMBER\",/" bower.json
```

Which searches the *version:* and replaces the part after it with the *RELEASE_NUMBER* variable (plus a ","). However, I can't seem to get this right in batch using

```
for /f .. in bower.json ..
```

kind of setups. I can't use cygwin so I have to convert the sed to windows runnable code.

Comment: Why can't you use cygwin?

Comment: My machine has it installed but the users of the script may not always have it installed. I do not want to force them to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest thing to a one-liner without requiring non-native utilities would be to use PowerShell's `replace` method.

```js
set "RELEASE_NUMBER=4.8"

powershell "(gc bower.json) -replace '(\"version\":\s*)[^,]+', '$1\"%RELEASE_NUMBER%\"' | out-file bower.json"
```

Scraping and manipulating structured data (such as JSON, XML, HTML, etc) as complicated flat text always makes me cringe though.  What if your JSON were minified?  If I were you, I'd parse the JSON as JSON and manipulate it as an object.  It takes a little more effort, but it's safer.  Save this with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "RELEASE_NUMBER=4.8"
set "JSONfile=bower.json"

cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%RELEASE_NUMBER%" "%JSONfile%"

goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    args = { 'version': WSH.Arguments(0), 'file': WSH.Arguments(1) },
    fHandle = fso.OpenTextFile(args.file, 1);

// import JSON methods from htmlfile COM object
htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
var JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON;

var struct = JSON.parse(fHandle.ReadAll());
struct.version = args.version;

fHandle.Close();
fHandle = fso.CreateTextFile(args.file, true);
fHandle.write(JSON.stringify(struct, null, '\t'));
fHandle.Close();
```

You might need to modify the `struct.version = args.version` line depending on the hierarchical structure of your JSON (i.e. `struct.childName[0].grandChild.version = args.version`).  If the position of the `"version"` key can't be predicted, you can search for and modify it with a recursive function:

```js
function findKey(haystack, needle) {
    for (var i in haystack) {
        if (needle == i) return haystack;
        else if (key = findKey(haystack[i], needle)) return key;
    }
}

var struct = JSON.parse(fHandle.ReadAll());
findKey(struct, 'version').version = args.version;
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. Never even thought about simply parsing the JSON from a batch file / batch call.